# Distributed system in Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, system, distributed

I'm planning to build a distributed system on top of Amazon EC2.

How can I get the network IP address of each machine (like 192.xxx.x.x)?

This way, when a new node enters the system, other nodes give a list of IP addresses for him to communicate.

Thanks!

Comment: You *could* write a program to do that - but you will find there are tools that already exist. I'd try asking on http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 1):

Use a framework like [chef](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home) or [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/) to organize your nodes. This will allow you to bootstrap instances as they start.

The way this works with Amazon EC2 is that it allows you to pass [*user-data*](http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts) to each instance -- generally a script of some sort to run commands, e.g. for bootstrapping.

If running this yourself is too much of an obstacle, I'd recommend a service like:

- [opscode platform](http://opscode.com/)
- [scalarium](http://www.scalarium.com/)
- [rightscale](http://www.rightscale.com/)
- [scalr](https://scalr.net/) (also [opensource](http://code.google.com/p/scalr/))

HTH

Answer (score 0):

If a "node enters the system" I assume that it connects to some port. And that's exactly where you get the IP from. e.g. in Java:

```
Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
InetAddress addr = socket.getInetAddress()
System.out.println("new host with IP " + addr.getHostAddress() + " entered the system");
```

Alternatively, you could resolve the FQDN of your system.

```
# bash
nslookup `hostname --fqdn`

# groovy
groovy -e 'println java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()'
```

The FQDN depends on your host configuration though and might resolve to 127.0.0.1 which isn't very helpful.

As a third option that's specific to EC2, you could also use the AWS SDK or EC2 CLI:

```
# using CLI
ec2-describe-instances | grep INSTANCE | cut -f4
```

This returns a list of public DNS names that resolve to private IPs when resolved from within EC2 (try piping the output into `xargs -n1 nslookup` on an EC2 instance or outside EC2 respectively). You could of course filter the list to only show instances started from special AMIs you're interested in.